# How to package WAR with a REST Client for Remote EJB (with Maven) in Java EE 6 environment?

Tags: rest, client, maven-3, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

Got a WAR Maven module with a REST Client, implemented as @Stateless EJB) in a module (say) "mycompany-client".

This REST Client invoke an EJB implemented in a EAR module, with a JAR module inside (say) "mycompany-business-service".
(EAR and JAR module are under a parent POM module)

WAR and EAR are running on a Weblogic 12C (Java EE 6).
*But IT COULD BE ON DISTINCT SERVERS.*

#### My module "mycompany-client" (war)

*REST CLIENT*

```
@Stateless
@Path("clusters")
public class ClusterResource {

    @EJB
    ClusterService service;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Cluster> getItems() {
        return service.getAllClusters();
    }
    [...]
```

#### My EJB module "mycompany-business-service" (a JAR in an EAR)

*EJB (with a Remote Business Interface)*

- Remote Interface (ClusterService)

  ```
  @Remote
  public interface ClusterService {

      public List<Cluster> getAllClusters();
  }
  ```
- Implementation (ClusterServiceBean)

  ```
      @Stateless
      @Remote(ClusterService.class)
      public class ClusterServiceBean implements ClusterService {

      @Override
      public List<Cluster> getAllClusters() {
          // Do the job
          return ...;
      }
      [...]
  ```

In the dependencies of my WAR (pom.xml), i have to declare a dependecy to my "mycompany-business-service" jar :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>mycompany-business-services</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>             <== with or without
    </dependency>
```

## *So what ?...*

*1) Choice 1 : using "provided" scope :* ?

As "mycompany-business-service" is already deployed on my Weblogic server, i thought to use "provided" scope.
But if i do this, the deploy (via the great "wls-maven-plugin") fails with a ClassNotFoundException concerning the service EJB to be injected !

*2) Choice 2 : no "provided" scope, jar embedded ?*

In this case, the injection and the call to EJB works perfectly... but but : the invoked EJB is the local/embedded one, ***NOT THE REMOTE ONE !***

**Finally, my question :**

Howto package WAR with a REST Client for Remote EJB to be injected ?

Comment: Could the solution be :
generate an EJB services JAR with only Interfaces, and not Implementations of my EJB (the one to be used in the WAR dependencies) ?

Comment: Generate only EJB Client jar (beside ALL EJB STUFF jar) ?... here : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html

Comment: In REST Client POM, declare only dependency on EJB Client jar ?... Using: <type>ejb-client</type> works.
Next !...